# Mysql connections reduction impact?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, lamp

I get around 4 million hits on my web server daily. On each page, I open 2 Mysql connections which get close after script execution.

After some optimisations done, for 10% of my requests .i.e. for 400k hits, I open single mysql connection now instead of 2.

After reducing Total Mysql connections per day, I checked Total Mysql No. of processes, sleeps etc, where I don't see any significant gain. It's almost same pre and post optimisation.

In which area I can expect to see the benefit in terms of performance? Will it be CPU utilisation? Memory benefit? IO?

I use LAMP stack.

Comment: Could be the mySQL cache https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-cache.html

Comment: Checkec. Its also almost the same pre and post optimisation.